# File won't show in folder, but will show in root directory?

Tags: html, css, cpanel

I got an empty website up and running online. Basic html5 page with a style link and a script link. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Taco Bell at midnight</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The `src's` are accurate, I have a folder in the same directory as the html page with the name css and js. When I try to visit them, it shows them as blank. However, when I drag the files out to the same directory as the parent, and update the `href`, it shows them with the content. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

It seems relevant to add I just purchased the domain today from GoDaddy, and am using x10hosting for free hosting.

UPDATE: The styles.css still appears in my home directory (in chrome, not cpanel) after being moved, and ctrl+f5'ing, and it now also appears in the folder css/styles.css as well???

UPDATE2: Now it appears as though the files are just updating really slowly? I see the changes in codeanywhere/cpanel immediately, but chrome takes like half an hour to get the changes, regardless of clearing my history/cache and ctrl+f5'ing.

Comment: Do you have these files sitting on a FTP? Could there be a permissions issue in play?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue

Comment: I'm using `codeanywhere.com`, but started using `cpanel` just now to try to fix it to no avail.

Comment: Make sure css and js folders are chmodded to 755 and the files themselves are 644

Comment: folders are 0755, and files are 0644. Issue still exists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x10hosting (free version, I haven't tested paid version) cache is really bad, this seems to be a server issue, sometimes it keeps showing files that you deleted hours ago, sometimes it won't show files that didn't exist beforem, you might need to wait for hours.